# how to free the memory of unordered_set?

Tags: c++, free, unordered-set

I wonder how to free the memory std::unordered_set took?

I think unordered_set::clear() just clear the set without free the memory.

I need to free the unordered_set hold by local function. Each time I called local function, it will consume some memory, so I need to free it at the end of local function.

Thank you

Comment: Is the `unordered_set` local to the function? If it is, then its memory will be correctly released at the end of the function without you needing to do anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to clear the memory of an `unordered_set` is the same as for any standard container:

```
set = std::unordered_set<T>()
```

You can also use:

```
std::unordered_set<T>().swap(set)
```

which was the usual way to release the memory from containers in the days before r-value refs.

You should replace `T` with the type of the objects contained in the set.

Comment: when I do this: std::tr1::unordered_set::swap(_closelist); it is showing'error: 'template<class _Value, class _Hash, class _Pred, class _Alloc> class std::tr1::unordered_set' used without template parameters' and when I do _closelist.swap(std::tr1::unordered_set()); it shows`error: missing template arguments before '(' token
`

Comment: Sorry... I left out part of the example. You will need to supply the template paramater to the `unordered_set` (see the edit).

Comment: so essentially we are assigning the set with a new empty type? I think my memory is not released.....i'm doing <pre><code>std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<int, 16> >().swap(_closelist);
    _closelist = std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<int, 16> >();

Comment: I test it with this code, it uses 2.7GB memory but only free to 2.5GB`code`//test free set//
 std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<int, 16> >_closelist;
 for(i =0;i<30000000;i++)
 {
  std::tr1::array<int, 16> test = {9,8,3,7,2,1,6,10,5,13,0,4,12,15,14,i};
  _closelist.insert(test);
 }
 std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<int, 16> >().swap(_closelist);
 
 printf("hahahahahahhahahaha\n\n\n\n\n\n");`code`

Comment: You do not need to do both `std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<int, 16> >().swap(_closelist);` and `_closelist = std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<int, 16> >();`. Either on its own is fine. You are right though. This is not guaranteed to result in an `unordered_set` which owns no memory whatsoever. What it will do, is reduce the memory consumption down to the small initial memory consumption of a default-constructed `unordered_set`, which should be significantly less than the memory consumption of an `unordered_set` containing a lot of elements.

Comment: Yes....it will reduce the memory for sure. Do you know any function for unordered_set like malloc and free that can free all the memory? I think we can not use malloc for unordered_set?

Answer (score 2):

`unordered_set` automatically releases the memory it takes if its on the stack:

```
void some_function()
{
    unordered_set<int> set;
    // use the set
} // set memory will be deallocated automatically here
```

Answer (score 0):

The set is a node-based container, so the memory for the nodes is indeed freed up properly. But since the hash table may have grown to many buckets, you could try `rehash(1)` to make it smaller again -- but that's only a hint; the set isn't required to reduce the number of buckets.

Comment: I need to free the unordered_set hold by local function. Each time I called local function, it will consume some memory, so I need to free it at the end of local function.